# Multiple Shopify layout scripts - "script" and "javascript" types

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

I noticed that on Shopify it will load every layout's script whether or not that layout is actually being used. Furthermore, there appears to be type types that show up in the Network panel: a `script` and then a corresponding `javascript` type (see image):

[image]

So, 2 questions:

1. Why are these layout scripts being downloaded when the layout is not being used? and
2. What is the difference b/t these 2 script types?

Comment: It looks theme-specific and Shopify doesn't load any specific scripts by default, you need to check theme install or APP-like page builder that appends most of the scripts like these ones.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. The problem is coming from Theme Kit's webpack config. There's a `webpack/script-tags.html` file that includes rendering logic that assumes you either want to load or preload every script in the assets folder - which is dumb. A simple update to this conditional will stop this from happening.